# Print to terminal window in python

Tags: python, linux, terminal

I am trying to debug my code and see if I am entering a loop when I should. I am running this on a Linux server. The python script gets executed via website. I want to print something to the terminal window to let me know I entered the loop. I have been trying:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["echo" + "Statement"])
```

How do you print to the terminal window through a python script?

Comment: If it's running through a website, it doesn't sound like it's connected to a tty. What tty do you expect it to print to and why?

Comment: Use the logging module to log things. Opening a subprocess to run echo is not a good idea, even if it would work...

Comment: I would like it to print to tty2.  The script is being ran server side.  The purpose of the script is to change the static IP via web interface.  I would like to print a variable or two from the script to the screen to ensure that the right variables are getting passed.  If that is possible.

Comment: @Wooble  I will look into.  I have not used that module yet.

Answer (score 0):

Casual print() should do it in case you run the server from the terminal window.
Otherwise, you need to pipe output somewhere, probably to file like this

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open('/tmp/server.log', 'w')
```

and then in your terminal window do

```
tail -f /tmp/server.log
```

which will hook to the file and print any changes, therefore getting effect you wanted.

Comment: Would this interfere with writing to other files?  I write to a temp interface file which gets copied over to interfaces when done.

Comment: no, it should not interfere with anything. it will only change location for print. let us know if it worked for you

Comment: I was unable to get it to work.  I am not sure if permissions are stopping it or not.

Comment: what about `print("Statement", file=open("/tmp/server.log","a"))`? also, if you are using python2, make sure you add `from __future__ import print_function`